# Cimg border reading

Tags: c++, image, cimg

```
#include "CImg.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

class Imagen{
public:

CImg<int> contorno(char[60]);
CImg<int> binarizar(char[60],int);
CImg<int> grises(char[60]);};

CImg<int> Imagen::binarizar(char nombreImagen[60],int factorB){
CImg<int> imagen(nombreImagen);
unsigned char r,g,b,promedio;
CImg<int> imagenB(imagen.width(),imagen.height(),1,1);
for(int x=0;x<imagenB.width();x++){
    for(int y=0;y<imagenB.height();y++){
            r=imagen(x,y,0,0);
            g=imagen(x,y,0,1);
            b=imagen(x,y,0,2);
            promedio=((r+g+b)/3);

            if( promedio>=factorB)
                imagenB(x,y,0,0)=255;

            if( promedio<=factorB)
                imagenB(x,y,0,0)=0;

    }}

return imagenB;}

CImg<int> Imagen::grises(char nombreImagen[60]){
CImg<int> imagen(nombreImagen);
CImg<int> imagenG(imagen.width(),imagen.height(),1);
cimg_forXYC(imagen,x,y,c) {
   imagenG(x,y,0)= (imagen(x,y,0)+imagen(x,y,1)+imagen(x,y,2))/3;
}
return imagenG;}

CImg<int> Imagen::Contorno(char nombreImagen[60]){
CImg<int>imagen(nombreImagen);
CImg<int>imagenCont(imagen.width(),imagen.height(),1);
 CImg<int>imagenGris2(imagen.width(),imagen.height(),1);
int a,b,c,d;
for(int x=0;x<imagen.width();x++){
    for(int y=0;y<imagen.height();y++){
            imagenGris2=(imagen(x,y,0)+imagen(x,y,1)+imagen(x,y,2))/3;
            a = imagenGris2(x,y,0);
            b = -imagenGris2(x+1,y+1,0);
            c = imagenGris2(x+1,y,0);
            d = -imagenGris2(x,y+1,0);
        imagenCont(x,y,0) = (sqrt(pow((a+b),2)+pow((c+d),2)));


    }
}
return imagenCont; }

int main () {

Imagen img;
char nomImg [60];
int opcion, factorBinarizar;
cout<<"ñññ."<<endl<<endl;
cout<<"Manipulacion de Imagenes Basica."<<endl<<endl;
cout<<"Ingrese el nombre de la imagen: "<<endl;
cin>>nomImg;

do{
    CImg<int> nvaImagenGris, nvaImagenBin, nvaImagenCont;
    cout<<"Seleccione una opcion:"<<endl<<endl<<"[1].visualizar escala de grises.\n[2].Visualizar la imagen binarizada.\n[3].Visualizar contornos de la imagen.\n[4].Guardar las imagenes y salir.\n";
    cin>>opcion;

    switch(opcion){
        case 1:nvaImagenGris=img.grises(nomImg);break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"Ingrese el numero factor de binarizacion:"<<endl;
            cin>>factorBinarizar;
            nvaImagenBin=img.binarizar(nomImg,factorBinarizar);
            break;
        case 3:
            nvaImagenCont=img.Contorno(nomImg);
            break;
        case 4:
            nvaImagenGris.save("ImModGris.bmp");
            nvaImagenBin.save("ImModBin.bmp");
            nvaImagenCont.save("ImModCont.bmp");
        break;
        default:
            cout<<"opcion incorrecta"<<endl;
        break;
    }
    if(opcion==1){
        CImgDisplay ventana(nvaImagenGris, "Imagen grises",1 );
        ventana.wait(3000);}
        else if (opcion==2){
        CImgDisplay ventaNa(nvaImagenBin, "Imaen Binarizada",1 );
        ventaNa.wait(3000);}
        else if (opcion==3){
        CImgDisplay ventanA(nvaImagenCont,"Contorno de la Imagen",1);
        ventanA.wait(3000);}

}while(opcion != 4);
return 0;}
```

I have problems with the "contorno" method, it is suposed to show only de borders of a .bmp image, but instead it shows me a black window, I am new using CImg so I don't know why this is happening, any idea and/or solution for this?

I'm using `code::blocks` on a windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure what you mean by "only show the borders" -- the code appears to be trying to compute `sqrt( (left+right)^2 + (top+bottom)^2 )` for each pixel in the image (and assumes anything past the boundaries is 0).
2. The problem is that you are initializing `imagenGris2` to a single number each time inside the loop, and then trying to access it as if it were an image. You should delete the first line inside the loop and outside the loop replace it with:

`imagenGris2=(imagen.get_channel(0)+imagen.get_channel(1)+imagen.get_channel(2))/3;`